# Problema con classpath

Tags: java, consola

Tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar mi programa, o creo que es eso, porque mi programa (geany) me compila el programa pero a la hora de ejecutar sale el error que os pasare en la foto.

Creo que es del `classpath` porque si hago javac HolaMundo.java me compila, pero despues con java HolaMundo no me lo ejecuta, sin embargo, si pongo: java -cp . HolaMundo sí lo hace. Me gustaría que me dijerais el motivo, os dejo aquí el problema en pantalla y las rutas de mis variables:

> path:%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin
>   classpath:%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin

(tambien siempre tengo que poner desktop para compilar, supongo que será por guardar ahi los programas)

problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez de abrir otra pregunta nueva duplicada deberías añadir esta información a tu pregunta anterior. Si las respuestas no te han valido puedes comentarlas para saber por qué no te funcionaron. Confía en la comunidad y usa las herramientas que tienes en vez de duplicar preguntas.

Comment: @Dev.Joel es un duplicado hecho por el mismo usuario solo que aquí ha añadido información nueva. Podría haberlo hecho en la anterior y verificar las respuestas.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n personar, soy nuevo en este foro, es exactamente el mismo error, pido disculpas.

Answer (score 1):

En windows debes incluir el directorio actual en donde se encuentra la clase(**.class**) que quieres ejecutar,como **"."**, como se muestra a continuación en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo: **.**;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\xbean.jar;C:\xmlbeans-2.5.0\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar.......

O de lo contrario así:

## En Unix

java -cp utilities.jar:. mypackage.MyClass

## En Windows

java -cp utilities.jar;. mypackage.MyClass

Comment: Perdona pero, creo que lo tengo exactamente asi, mi ruta del classpath es esta :      %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin

Comment: O de lo contrario también puedes ejecutarla así:

Comment: Así? Como ? @Darth Vader

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta, también la puedes ejecutar de esa manera con **"java -cp"** e incluyes los directorios en donde se encuentre la clase o los jars que se ocupan.

Comment: Sí, eso mismo me dijo un amigo, y funciona, pero sigo sin entender porque me da error desde el geany o consola sin hacer ese truco,  y no puedo hacerlo como todo el mundo :(

Comment: Tal vez tengas un conflicto con alguno de los jars que están en la variable **CLASSPATH** del sistema, te sugiero que quites todos los jars de la variable  **CLASSPATH** y solo pongas los que funcionan que son los que ocupas con el **"java -cp"** y vuelvas a ejecutar desde la consola, solo recuerda que en WIndows después de que cambias la variable, tienes que abrir otra consola para que los cambios tengan efecto.